# Closed simple curves in $\mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^2$

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, differential-topology, riemann-surfaces, curves-and-surfaces, surfaces

**EDIT:** The well known [Jordan curve theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_curve_theorem) says: let $C\subset S^2$ be a closed simple curve on the 2-sphere. Then its complement $S^2\backslash C$ consists of two connected components, both homeomorphic to discs (in fact it is known that the closure of each component is homeomorphic to the closed disk by [Jordan-Schoenflies theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schoenflies_problem)).

> Is there a version of the Jordan theorem for closed simple curves in real projective plane $\mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^2$? (The curve might be assumed to be smoothly imbedded.)

A reference would be helpful.

**ADDED:** Given the comment by  HenrikRüping below, I realized that for my purposes it suffices to assume that the homology class of $C$ vanishes in $H_1(\mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^2,\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$.

Comment: of course if we look at a closed simple curve representing the generator of $\pi_1$, the complement should have only one connected component homeomorphic to a disc.

Comment: @HenrikRüping: Many thanks. Corrected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If C is null-homologous, then the complement of C has two components: a disk and a Möbius strip (as one sees since the preimage of C in the 2-sphere is 2 disjoint Jordan curves).
If C is not null-homologous, then the complement of C is a single disk.

Comment: Is there a reference for this? (I think I would be able to prove it, but I prefer to just cite it)

Comment: You can probably make an easy proof just with the elementary theory of coverings and the Euler characteristic of the complement.

Answer (score 4):

Well, if you take the double cover, under your assumptions the lift is two simple closed curves in $S^2,$ the complement of which will be two disks and an annulus, so the original curve bounds a disk on one side.